# Hcaptcha CORS error even after adding domain to hosts file. (WINDOWS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, hcaptcha

As per the hcaptcha docs it says:
[image]

I have done this, but I still get a CORS error in my requests. I am visiting the URL from:
`http://test.mydomain.com:3000` and in my network requests it comes from the same URL.

My hosts file contains:
`127.0.0.1 test.mydomain.com`

I'm not sure what else to try.

```
  const handleVerificationSuccess = async (token, ekey) => {
    console.log(token);

    // Provide your secret key here
    const secretKey = '...';

    const response = await fetch('https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: `response=${token}&secret=${secretKey}`, // make sure to URL encode the data
    });

    const data = await response.json();
  };
```

[image]
[image]